# Querying for duplicates with the same timestamp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch the duplicates from my `prices` `table that have the same timestamp. However, I am a bit stuck on how to approach thhis.

What I've got so far:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS count,
article_id
FROM prices
GROUP BY article_id
HAVING count > 1;
```

This will produce a list with all duplicate prices, not concerned with whether or not the `timestamp` column differs.

Comment: `GROUP BY timestamp`

Comment: Well of course you would have to group by timestamp as well, so that your count and having are applied only on that “level”, and not on the article_id level.

Comment: @CBroe Of course! I just realise how stupid this question is. You're right, i wasn't thinking clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to my commenters and a thumbs down for me for not thinkng.

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS count,
article_id
FROM prices
GROUP BY article_id, price, tstamp
HAVING count > 1;
```

Adding `price` and `tstamp` to my `GROUP BY` clause did of course solve my problem.